# Javascript Game Thourght Processes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, game-engine

I'm a web developer, and have been for 10 years now. A couple of years ago I started making small games for advertising purpose, like slotmachines where you could win iPhones and such. VERY simple games.

Now I want to step it up a notch, and I have an idea I want to start with, but I lack knowledge on where to start, how to approach it and such.

**My game**

My game is a horse track carnival game, where you toss balls into holes which will make your horse move.

The ball game will be vertical, so this is what I need to know:

1. How can I aim the ball, dragging from it, the opposite way? Angry-birds-like.
2. How do I calculate the path and speed/duration?

Do I need a game libery, or what do you suggest me to do?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I aim the ball, dragging from it, the opposite way? Angry-birds-like.

The same as it has always have. It doesn't matter how you aim.

In the usual case of "flick/drag to shoot" games, you drag forwards. Angry birds does it in reverse, dragging backwards.

On both methods, whichever you choose, you get a point A and B (A line). Get the angle from the horizontal, and that's your elevation. Get the distance from A to B, that would be the strength of your shot. The farther you pull back, the stronger the shot should be.

> How do I calculate the path and speed/duration?

In the previous paragraph, we got an angle and strength. You can do it with a bit of physics (possibly with a ready-made physics library, or roll your own).